# Ocaml how to access elements in type definitions

Tags: ocaml

With the following type definition in ocaml:

```
type yearday = YMD of int * int * int
```

how would you access the different ints of the type? Like if I just wanted the value of the first int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parts of a value like this are accessed through pattern matching. Here's a function that returns the first int:

```
let y_of_ymd (YMD (y, _, _)) = y
```

Here's how it looks in the toplevel (OCaml REPL):

```
# let y_of_ymd (YMD (y, _, _)) = y;;
val y_of_ymd : yearday -> int = <fun>
# let myymd = YMD (2017, 4, 18);;
val myymd : yearday = YMD (2017, 4, 18)
# y_of_ymd myymd;;
- : int = 2017
#
```

**Update**

If you have more than one variant in your type you can use `match` to determine which kind of value is present

```
type yearday = YMD of int * int * int | YD of int * int

let y_of_yearday yearday =
    match yearday with
    | YMD (y, _, _) -> y
    | YD (y, _) -> y
```

There are more concise ways to write this, but I think this gives the best idea of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! A follow up question: if the type definition has two options like: type yearday = YMD of int * int * int | YD of int * int;; is there a way to make y_of_ymd that works for both definitions of the type, or a way to find out which of the definitions it is?

Comment: Yes, having different variants is probably more common that just having one variant. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot.